# VSCode ctrl+cmd+right shortcut doesn't work MacOS?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Keyboard shortcuts `ctrl+cmd+left` and `ctrl+cmd+right` arrows don't work, but up and down do!

Here is the keyboard event log for `ctrl+cmd+up`

```
\ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
/ Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
| Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
\ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
/ Soft dispatching keyboard event
\ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
/ Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,meta], code: MetaLeft, keyCode: 91, key: Meta
| Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,meta], code: MetaLeft, keyCode: 57 ('Meta')
\ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
/ Soft dispatching keyboard event
| Resolving ctrl+meta+[ArrowUp]
\ From 2 keybinding entries, no when clauses matched the context.
/ Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,meta], code: ArrowUp, keyCode: 38, key: ArrowUp
| Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,meta], code: ArrowUp, keyCode: 16 ('UpArrow')
| Resolving ctrl+meta+[ArrowUp]
\ From 2 keybinding entries, no when clauses matched the context.
+ Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.
```

But here it is for `ctrl+cmd+right`:

```
/ Soft dispatching keyboard event
\ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
/ Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
| Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
\ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
/ Soft dispatching keyboard event
\ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
/ Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,meta], code: MetaLeft, keyCode: 91, key: Meta
| Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,meta], code: MetaLeft, keyCode: 57 ('Meta')
\ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
+ Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.
```

As you can see, they're the same except with right and left arrows it doesn't dispatch the keyboard event.
There must be some setting I'm missing for this MacOS user as it does work on a different account

Comment: does anything here help? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues#troubleshoot-mac-keybindings

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, that keyboard combination was being hijacked by Rectangle - a layout shortcut app.